# Macro not dividing as it should

Tags: vba, divide

I have a macro that works but only when dividing up to 19.00. When 20.00 or higher is the number to be divided it divides to only 10.00 and that’s it.  What it’s suppose to do is divide any number up to 12.00 into 10 cells and any number over 12.00 it’s suppose to write the excess amount to the first number in the found pair.

Also, my macro refers to “Range("G" & found).Value = pair” at the end but nothing gets written. What I really need is to delete this or make it flexible to be written to specific cells, so it could be changed in the future or as I said just delete it.

If someone could take a look and see what I’m not seeing it sure would be appreciated.

```
Sub DIVIDE()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim pair As Variant, accumulator As Variant
Dim findFifteen As Double
Dim remainder As Long, found As Long

found = 1

For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
If Right(pair, 2) = 15 Then
    If pair.Offset(0, 1) <= 12 Then
        findFifteen = pair.Offset(0, 2) / 10
        remainder = 0
    Else
        findFifteen = 1
        remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2) Mod 10
    End If

    For Each accumulator In Range("A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40")
        If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1) Then
            accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + remainder
        End If
        accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + findFifteen
    Next accumulator
Range("G" & found).Value = pair
found = found + 1
End If
Next pair

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[EXCEL IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtiRq.jpg)

Comment: 1) `Dim pair as Range`, 2) `accumulator as Range`. 3) `Range("G" & Found).Value = pair.Value`

Comment: Can you show a sample of some data and then show an output?

Comment: It's hard-coded here that you are either diving by 10 or taking `Mod 10`

Comment: Fix   Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-"))) - 1   so that trailing right paren is moved 4 pos to the left.    Also, Fix indentation because   Range("G" & found)  only executes when  Right(pair, 2) = 15 .  Lastly, provide some sample data  for ("B30, F30, J30") and for their Offset(0, 1)

Comment: Hi, I have added my Excel image. The output from cell D30 would be a 1.20 (12.00 divided by 10 cells) in each of the 10 cells:A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40 with the exception of cell G40 which would have a value of 9.20 (1.00 from the div. by 12 and 8.00 as the extra above 12.00). Cell G40 is selected via the first number in cell B30 which is the number 8. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @NANCYSKYES, should `If pair.Offset(0, 1) <= 12` be  `If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12` (in your image, `pair.Offset(0,1)` appears to be empty)? All of your ranges implicitly refer to whichever sheet happens to be active whilst the code is running. It would be good to qualify the `workbook` and `worksheet`, so that the code outputs to the expected range.

Comment: Hi chillin you are right on the (0, 1) it should have been 2, my error. The empty cell is correct, I'm just not showing any data in it at the moment. I have tried the above changes but I can't get the macro to work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that's it's the division issue that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Could you assist in the actual code to Fix "Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-"))) - 1 so that trailing right paren is moved 4 pos to the left."